# Select unique values of an xml attribute

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a temp table with one column of xml type.

How can I write a single SELECT query to list all unique values of attribute 'z'

```
CREATE TABLE #TEST3 ([Data] XML)

INSERT INTO #TEST3 VALUES ('<r><a z="1" /> <a z="2" /></r>')

INSERT INTO #TEST  VALUES ('<r><b z="2" /><b z="3" /></r>')

INSERT INTO #TEST3 VALUES ('<r><c z="3"><c z="4" /></c></r>')
```

Comment: look up the `DISTINCT` keyword

Answer (score 0):

```
Select
Distinct t.m.value( '@z[1]', 'varchar(max)' ) ZAttribute
From
    #Test3 tempTable
    Cross Apply tempTable.Data.nodes( '/your/node/path/here' ) t(m)
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.